# Polymorphism - What am I not getting?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, polymorphism

I am having an issue with polymorphism in C#. I have an object that implements an interface, however I cannot represent a collection of the objects as a collection of interfaces. This flies in the face of my understanding of polymorphism. So I was wondering where I have gone wrong.

```
[TestFixture]
class Tester
{
    [Test]
    public void Polymorphism()
    {
        var list = new List<Foo> {new Foo {Name = "Item"}};

        Assert.That(list, Is.InstanceOf<IList>());
        Assert.That(list[0], Is.InstanceOf<Foo>());
        Assert.That(list[0], Is.InstanceOf<IBar>());

        // why are the rest true but this false?
        Assert.That(list, Is.InstanceOf<IList<IBar>>());
    }
}

internal interface IBar
{
}

internal class Foo : IBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: IBar is the interface so when you use List<IBar> the last Assert will work

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479859.aspx#fundamentals_topic12

Comment: This is all about contravariance and covariance. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: In short: a bowl of bananas is not a bowl of fruit because the allowed operations are different. A bowl of bananas rejects the addition of an apple, a bowl of fruit does not.

Comment: @EricLippert: thanks for that analogy. It really helps illustrate the variance stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of variance, not polymorphism.

If a List-of-Foo was also an IList-of-IBar, the following would work:

```
class Another : IBar {}
IList<IBar> list = new List<Foo>();
list.Add(new Another());
```

Then we've added an Another to a list of Foo. Which is an error. The compiler stopped you making a mistake.

Note that recent compilers / .net versions support variance via "in"/"out". So a List-of-Foo is fine as an IEnumerable-of-IBar. Because that is guaranteed to only *return* Foo (not accept them), and all Foo are also IBar - hence it is safe.

Comment: Why `Assert.That(list, Is.InstanceOf<IList<Foo>>());` returns false? Shouldn't it be true?

Comment: Thanks Marc. That IEmumerable being covariant really helped me out.

Comment: @Rohit the question is about IList-of-IBar, not IList-of-Foo

Comment: Yeah. I was just curious so thought of asking you. Should i post a seperate question for this?

Comment: @Rohit no need; a List-of-Foo is trivially assignable to IList-of-Foo

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my two cents in as well.  The issue you're encountering can be understood better if you increase your understanding of covariance and contravariance (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

I modified your code a bit and came up with this working test method:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
var list = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Item" } };
Assert.IsNotNull(list as IList);
Assert.IsNotNull(list[0] as Foo);
Assert.IsNotNull(list[0] as IBar);
Assert.IsNotNull(list as IList<Foo>);
Assert.IsNotNull((IList<Foo>)list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Foo>
```

The list is a `List<Foo>`, not a `List<IBar>`. Even though `Foo` implements `IBar`, the list itself it still a list of `Foo`.

So you cannot add any other type that implements `IBar` to that list. Only `Foo`'s, which obviously is a `Foo` or any type that derives from `Foo` too, as that would also be a `Foo`. I've said `Foo` too much.

If you wish to add any type that implements `IBar`, then you can make the list a collection of `IBar` instead:

```
var list = new List<IBar> { new Foo { Name = "Item" } };
```

Comment: You should just explain why a list of `Foo` is not also a list of `IBar` (see the comments for the question). You are taking that for granted even though that's exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: The question was why does the assert fail